# squeezebox ajax mootools

Tags: ajax, joomla, mootools, squeezebox

I use the modal window a fair bit in joomla and just found out that it doesn't work with ajax added links. What is the code I need to have the modal window work with those links?

I'm better at jquery than moo tools ...

Thanks,

Mat

I found this code but can't get it to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
   SqueezeBox.initialize({
    ajaxOptions: {
        evalScripts: true
    }
});
//SqueezeBox.initialize({});
   $$('a.modal').each(function(el) {
      el.addEvent('click', function(e) {
         new Event(e).stop();
         SqueezeBox.fromElement(el);
      });
   });
});

window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    window.addEvent('load', function(){

      //alert('clicked!');

      SqueezeBox.fromElement($('a.modal'));

    });

 });
</script>
```

Comment: Alternately maybe since I use jquery there is a good jquery modal window I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I use Rokbox (Mootools) from Rockettheme available for free here : http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-downloads/club/1005-rokbox

A must have :)

Comment: Cheers mate. Now I just thought what if I add onclick code to each ajax link. onclick="mootools relevant code" what would the code be?

Comment: If you want to load an external page with Rokbox :<br />
`<a href="http://google.com" rel="rokbox[fullscreen]">Open Google in fullscreen</a>`
<br/>
Or use this to load page with a defined size rokbox window (400px 300px):<br/>
`<a href="http://google.com" rel="rokbox[400 300]">Open Google in fullscreen</a>`

Comment: A link to the [online documentation](http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-joomla/rokbox#documentation)